# How to control variable value in a REPO through azure devops?

Tags: git, powershell, azure-devops, devops

I have a git repository that contains folders which has some basic PowerShell scripts.
One of the scripts is as below:

`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File testRun.ps1 -Environment **PROD** > c:\ssp\prod.log*`

I have created a new release that copy those folders and paste it into to different environments.

I want azure DevOps(VSTS) to change the bold marked environment value above(**PROD**) based upon the nature of the release. Example For UAT release I want the environment value to be filled as UAT and similar with other environments(PROD, PRE PROD etc).

How can we achieve it through VSTS?

Comment: Define a variable in your release. Pass that variable value to the script.

Comment: Actually this script is inside a folder, how can we pass through it?